# Log the size of the complete page load including HTML, CSS and Javascript

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, log4j, tomcat7

I want to Log the size of the complete page load including HTML, CSS and Javascript in the jsp Servlet Application.

Anyone suggest me the efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Evey container has the support to log web requests. You should be able to log the following:

1. request url
2. HTTP Method
3. Response status code
4. Response size
5. Request size.

For tomcat here is how you can do,

http://www.techstacks.com/howto/configure-access-logging-in-tomcat.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I think request size through tomcat is not there in the mentioned blog. Also is there any way we can get the tomcat access log value through java to log inside application

Comment: You should be able to log request size also.